# Implementing different styles within a Silverlight 5 application

Tags: xaml, silverlight, styles, themes

I have a Silverlight 5 application, it is an image viewing system photographers use to show their images to their customers.  My photographers want to be able to change the styling of the application.  At a minimum they want both a light and dark option, in the end, they want a lot more customization then that.

I have used styles within the application (yes, there is a lot of clean up that needs to be done) but once I have one xaml file with all the colors, how do I set it up so that the customer can pick between to different looks, the light and the dark?

Does anyone know of any examples out there on how to do this?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question, you'll have to setup separate Resource Dictionaries and then you could use an example like [this](https://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2009/05/load-xaml-resource-dictionaries-at-runtime/), but first you'll have to create an overall theme for your different elements and to truly get what you want you'll probably end up having to edit some of the default style templates for various controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris, you hit the nail on the head with that link!  I didn't know there was such a thing as DynamicResource, which lead me to what I am seeking:

[Silverlight 5’s New Style Data Binding](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jprosise/silverlight-5-s-new-style-data-binding)